# Get the list of all the users of all the databases using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, python

```
db.command('usersInfo')
```

The above command gives the list of users in the database in which the command is run.

```
command_result = db.command(
    {
        'usersInfo': {'user': 'user', 'db': 'mydatabase'},
        'showPrivileges': True
    } )
```

The above code gives information about the users in the 'mydatabase' database.

But I want to list all the users in all the databases. Can anyone tell me what command I can use in python for that?

```
s = myclient.admin.command({'usersInfo' :{'forAllDBs: true'}}) print(s)
```

When I am using above command, I am getting an error. I am using `pymongo`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
for (let d of db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } ).databases ) {
   db.getSiblingDB(d.name).getUsers()
}
```

This is javascript code in mongo shell, should be no big issue to convert it into python.

Comment: i dont know how i can convert this in python

Comment: It's a simple loop over an array. Check https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/get-mongodb-database-and-collection-names-with-pymongo-and-python-644

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it... This works:

```
s = myclient.admin.command('usersInfo', {'forAllDBs': True})
print(s)
```

With assistance from the [docs for command()](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.command).